# Is there a method to make a scrollable SingleChoiceAction List in devexpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I recently started using Devexpress 17.2. I have this viewcontroller where i have to filter some data. The items on the SingleChoiceAction List are acting as filter criteria, but the problem is there are too many items in this list, 500 or more. Is there a way to make this SingleChoiceAction, scrollable or to make some kind of pagination?

```
private SingleChoiceAction FilterList;
FilterList = new SingleChoiceAction(this, "filter", PredefinedCategory.Filters) {
    ImageName = "Action_Filter", Caption = "Filter", ItemType = SingleChoiceActionItemType.ItemIsOperation
};
foreach (var lc in listCriteria) {
    var item = new ChoiceActionItem(string.Format("Filter: {0}", lc), lc);
    _actionFilterByRepo.Items.Add(item);
}
```

listCriteria has many data which are retrieved from a database

Comment: Share some code which you have done so far.

Comment: private SingleChoiceAction FilterList;  
FilterList= new SingleChoiceAction(this, "filter", PredefinedCategory.Filters){  
    ImageName = "Action_Filter",
    Caption = "Filter",
    ItemType = SingleChoiceActionItemType.ItemIsOperation  
};

foreach (var lc in listCriteria){  
 var item = new ChoiceActionItem(string.Format("Filter: {0}", lc), lc);    
      _actionFilterByRepo.Items.Add(item);  
 }  
listCriteria has many data which are retrieved from a database